# How to repeat train and test 10 times in R

Tags: r, keras, sample

I'm using Keras and I'd like to make 10 different train and test samples to repeat the fit function with those samples.

```
for (i in 1:10) {
## 75% of the sample size
smp_size <- floor(0.8 * nrow(cifarSmall$x))

## set the seed to make your partition reproducible
set.seed(123)
train_ind <- sample(seq_len(nrow(cifarSmall$x)), size = smp_size)


train_x <- cifarSmall$x[train_ind,,,]

train_y <- cifarSmall$y[train_ind]

test_x <- cifarSmall$x[-train_ind,,,]
test_y <- cifarSmall$y[-train_ind]

conjuntos_train_x[i] <- c(train_x)

}
```

Comment: What I'm trying to do is a Hold-out 80-20, 10 times so I want 10 different train and test sets

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps do 10 times cross validation:

```
n <- 5
repeat <- 2
for(j in 1:repeat){
  indexes <- split(sample(1:nrow(iris)),1:n)
  for (i in 1:n) {     
  test_x <- iris[indexes[[i]],]      
  train_x <- iris[-indexes[[i]],]

  ## train, evaluate keras model
  ## do some hyper tuning
  }
}
```

Good thing about cross validation is that you assume Independence between train and test sets, while maintaining large proportion of data for training. Now the test errors and metrics are independent, so you can compare and tune your models, assuming i.i.d. in the input data.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is a Hold-out 80-20, 10 times so I want 10 different train and test sets

Comment: So do 5 fold  CV twice. That s called repeated CV. I ll edit.